# find element in array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, char

hey guys I am trying to solve a problem that requires making a program that searches for number k in n strings in an array and all its previous numbers including zero and finally calculates how many strings in array have these numbers . for example if the input is 2 strings ("0123","012") and search for  number 1 the output should be 2 in this case .

so I made an array of strings and 2 loops to search in every char in every string (every element in array) but my program gives me wrong answer I don't know why , am I using a wrong function to search (find function) or what ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main() {
  int n, k, sum = 0, good = 0;

  cin >> n >> k;
  string x[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> x[i];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  // string loop
  {
    for (int m = 0; m <= k; m++)  // char loop
    {
      char c = '0' + m;
      size_t search = x[i].find(c);

      if (search != string::npos) {
        sum++;
      }
    }
    if (sum == (k + 1)) good++;
  }

  cout << good;
}
```

Comment: Do not ask for user input in your [mre]. Instead, initialize your variables to the simplest values that demonstrate the error. Tell us the expected and actual output. For bonus points, [explain why your code should be correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: When you start looking at the second string, `sum` is not zero but whatever value was left over after processing the first string. You keep adding to `sum`, it grows ever larger, and won't be equal to `k + 1` more than once.

Comment: The size of an array variable must be compile time constant in C++. User input is not compile time constant. The program is ill-formed. If you want an array with dynamic size, you need to allocate it dynamically. The simplest way to create a dynamic array is to use `std::vector`.